# Why does the ggplotly function not display in my Rmarkdown ioslides

Tags: markdown, plotly, knitr, ggplotly, ioslides

I am trying to make a slide with an interactive graph on it. The ggplotly function works in the console but does not show in the markdown chunk - the corresponding slide is blank. A normal plot shows up just fine.

```
---
title: "TEST"
author: "me"
date: "19 February 2020"
output:
  beamer_presentation: default
  ioslides_presentation: default
---
```

### Test (working)

```
library(plotly)
df = data.frame(a = c(1:3,1:10))
p = ggplot(df, aes(x=a))+ geom_bar()
p
```

### Test2 (not working)

```
library(plotly)
df = data.frame(a = c(1:3,1:10))
p = ggplot(df, aes(x=a))+ geom_bar()
ggplotly(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by opening directly into browser from .html file and not via RStudio